# Erro conexão Delphi 6 - Mysql 4.1 - libmysql.dll - Windows 8

Tags: mysql, delphi

Olá. Muitos já devem ter viso posts similares sobre essa dúvida, mas já fiz todas as ações sugeridas, e não roda.

Preciso conectar o Delphi6 no Mysql 4.1 (não posso utilizar outras versões) tem que ser estas devido ao servidor que roda o sistema no momento. Talvez o Mysql 4.0, mas o delphi tem que ser o 6.

Quando utilizo o SQLConnection (já tentei com componentes de terceiros também) sempre dá erro de **Unable to load libmysql.dll**

Baixei algumas versões da dll, coloquei nas pastas do Windows\System32, SysWow64, na pasta BIN do Delphi, na pasta onde está o projeto do Delphi, configurei o caminho de algumas destas pastas como variável de ambiente do Delphi 6, mas nada funciona.

Gostaria de saber como identificar se a dll que tenho e a certa, e onde eu configuro isso no Delphi, ou no Windows, etc.

Obrigado

Comment: Mas não precisa copiar as coisas na system32, você geralmente "cola" na pasta do Delphi. Ao menos na maioria dos softwares que eu uso (não trabalho com Delphi, não posso afirmar), geralmente colocamos as dlls na mesma pasta, ou em um pasta indicada. Porém se realmente eles indicam para colocar as system32 então o problema pode ser a versão do Delphi, você pode estar usando uma versão 64bit então você teria que baixar a dll para 64bit e colar na pasta `SysWoW64` ao invés de `system32`. Nota a dll também deve ser 64bit se o delphi for 64bit.

Comment: Amigo, tenta dar uma olhada aqui: https://claudiocoelho.wordpress.com/2009/09/11/delphi-7-mysql-5-unable-to-load-libmysql-dll/

Comment: Mais uma dica, veja essa pergunta no SO em Inglês: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951319/unable-to-load-libmysql-dll

Comment: Executei as sugestões passadas, e até instalei uma maquina virtual com XP, mas não roda de forma nenhuma. mesmo utilizando a libmysql.dll que vem junto com a instalação do database, não roda. Agradeço se alguém tiver mais alguma sugestão.

Comment: Qual é o tamanho da sua dll. Eu tenho um sistema feito em delphi 6 com mysql 4.1 e também me bati para rodar. Só foi com a dll que tenho hoje, de 212KB.